# Python requests session for form posting does not seem to persist

Tags: python, html, session, python-requests, persistence

I am trying to (1) log into a website with requests, then (2) update the values of six text fields on a login-restricted subpage. My code seems to log in successfully. The status code is 200 and the output returned from print(login.text) shows the HTML for the landing page only after successful login.

However, once I try to post data to the six fields on the next page (diary_url), my requests session does not seem to remain logged in.

Does anyone know what is causing my issue? Relevant HTML and Python below.

**HTML of login page**

```html
<div class="member-login">
    
    <h2>Member Login</h2>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li>
      </li>
      <li class="username-field">
          <label>Email Address:</label>
          <input autocapitalize="none" class="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Email Address" size="12" type="text" value="" />
      </li>
      <li class="password-field">
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input class="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" size="12" type="password" value="" />
      </li>
      <li class="remember-field">
        <input checked="checked" class="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="remember_me" type="checkbox" value="1" />
        <label for="remember_me" >Remember me next time</label>
      </li>
      <li class="submit" >
        <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
      </li>
      <li class="or or-static-page" >
        <span>or</span>
        <div class="hr"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="facebook-login-css bttn btn-primary" id="facebook-login-css">Log in with Facebook</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**HTML of second page where I would like to submit new data via post**

```html
<div class="col-1">

        <h4>Meal Names:</h4>

        <ol class="fieldset">

            
              <li class="field">
                <input class="text" id="meal_names_0_description" maxlength="30" name="meal_names[0][description]" size="30" type="text" value="A. 35P 3V 0F 20C" />
              </li>
            
              <li class="field">
                <input class="text" id="meal_names_1_description" maxlength="30" name="meal_names[1][description]" size="30" type="text" value="B. 35P 3V 0F 20C" />
              </li>
            
              <li class="field">
                <input class="text" id="meal_names_2_description" maxlength="30" name="meal_names[2][description]" size="30" type="text" value="C. 35P 3V 10F 20C" />
              </li>
            
              <li class="field">
                <input class="text" id="meal_names_3_description" maxlength="30" name="meal_names[3][description]" size="30" type="text" value="D. 35P 3V 10F 35C" />
              </li>
            
              <li class="field">
                <input class="text" id="meal_names_4_description" maxlength="30" name="meal_names[4][description]" size="30" type="text" value="E. 35P 3V 15F 55C" />
              </li>
            
              <li class="field">
                <input class="text" id="meal_names_5_description" maxlength="30" name="meal_names[5][description]" size="30" type="text" value="WO. 35P 0V 0F 65C" />
              </li>

        </ol>

      </div>
```

**Custom Python code to log into the webiste then submit the new fieldnames**

```
import secrets, requests

meals={
    0:'Leaf',
    1:'Crackor',
    2:'Stinky',
    3:'Grape',
    4:'Appol',
    5:'Bellay'
}

mealnames={
    'meal_names_0_description': meals[0],
    'meal_names_1_description': meals[1],
    'meal_names_2_description': meals[2],
    'meal_names_3_description': meals[3],
    'meal_names_4_description': meals[4],
    'meal_names_5_description': meals[5]
}

payload={
    'username': secrets.user,
    'password': secrets.pw
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    login_url="https://www.myfitnesspal.com/account/login"
    diary_url='https://www.myfitnesspal.com/account/diary_settings'

    login = s.post(login_url, data=payload)
    if(login.status_code!=200):
        print("BAD")

    go_to_diary = s.get(diary_url)
    diary_page = s.post(diary_url, data=mealnames)
```

Comment: A you sure they use cookie/session based login? Maybe that's token-based authorization?

Comment: Thank you for this response, very kind of you. You are in fact correct, they use a header element named "authenticity_token" that I needed to grab and include in my session header.